# Can you tell me what does this error means?

Tags: django, docker, deployment

I am trying to deploy my django docker application to Amazon EC2 , So first I pushed the image to DockerHub and then pulling it . I am using Amazon Linux Instance .

These are the images I already pulled from DockerHub and I try to run shoaib9942/signals_api image --

[image]

I started the docker service and try to run it but it gives an error this is the error --

[image]

Also, when I run this command locally it also giving me the same error but when I run docker-compose up then everthing is working fine as it should be .

Does this error has some obvious meaning ?

Comment: Can you add the errors as text, instead of as images?  Having enough source code to reproduce the issue would be useful as well, at least your image's `Dockerfile` and the specific `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this error (`repository may not exist or require 'docker login'`) was seen as intermittent before (meaning it went away when retrying, as [in this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=922630)), check if the issue persists.

This might be related to Docker API, which [had recently a security alert](https://www.techradar.com/news/docker-apis-under-attack-once-again).